# Why does this loop break my code?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Fair warning, I am a novice with javascript and ool. I am trying to put together a simple script to parse data out to a web socket. The script should be able to handle an infinite number of payloads.

This code works, although can only handle on payload at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node 
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var i=1

socket = io.connect('http://10.0.9.1:80');
var data = JSON.parse(process.argv[2]);
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('Emitting');
    socket.emit('widget', data);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Wrapping the code in a loop with a logic test breaks it. No syntax errors, but  it does not seem to call the emit method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node 
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var i=1
var data

while (true) {
    i++
    if ( process.argv[i] ) {
    socket = io.connect('http://10.0.9.1:80');
    data = JSON.parse(process.argv[2]);
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('Emitting');
        socket.emit('widget', data);
    });
    } else {
        process.exit(0);
    };
};
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `socket.on('connect', function(){}` inside a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many mistakes in my first attempt. Clues from ControlAltDel and mrid made me realize my loop structure was all wrong. The loop should have been placed within the on('connect') like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var i=1
var data

socket = io.connect('http://10.0.9.1:80');

socket.on('connect', function(){
    while (true) {
        i++;
        if ( process.argv[i] ) {
            data = JSON.parse(process.argv[i]);
            console.log('Emitting ');
            socket.emit('widget', data);
        } else {
            process.exit(0);
        };
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The sockets you are creating are async, so you end up creating a bunch of sockets and then call process.exit(0) before there's time to establish the connection

Comment: Thanks controlAltDel. I've moved the socket = io.connect before the loop and removed the process.exit(0) line. No real change though. I never get the console.log('Emitting')

Comment: so then either process.argv.length is less than 3, or your connect call is never connecting, or you are getting an error.